# Create PageObject elements inside a function

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I am trying to create page object elements inside a function so that i could change the element property depending upon the parameter.

```
class SomePage
  include PageObject


  def create_element(x)
    div(:my_element, :id => "something-{x}")
  end

end
```

But when i call this function i am getting below error:

```
undefined method `div' for #<SomePage:0x35a6be8> (NoMethodError).
```

If i write the same code with a fixed property value, it works fine. But i need to create elements in the above way using a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method should look like this:

```rb
def create_element(x)
  div_element(:id => "something-#{x}")
end
```

Method #div is [Accessor](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/page-object/PageObject/Accessors#div-instance_method). It only defines methods for you. It's been designed to be used in the field of a class.